# When did "Happy ending" get used as a euphemism?

Tags: etymology, slang, euphemisms

Once upon a time, [happy ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending) was only used in the context of fiction. But since then, it's been used as a [euphemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erotic_massage#Cultural_references) for sexual release at the end of an erotic massage.

When did "Happy ending" get the second meaning? Was this meaning made popular by non-native speakers of English?

[Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happy%20ending&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappy%20ending%3B%2Cc0) isn't useful because of the existing meaning, and the Online Etymology Dictionary pointedly only refers to the [original meaning](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=happy):

> Happy ending in the literary sense recorded from 1756.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*OED* has the earliest citation of the slang term *happy ending* from 1999:

> ‘We are seeing more and more women accompanying their men in here,’ she says of her parlour, which provides ‘massage only’ but with a guaranteed ‘happy ending’.
>
> <sub>*Weekend Austral.* (Nexis) 14 Aug. (Review section) 8</sub>

Comment: [*Cassel's dictionary of slang*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA679&dq=slang+dictionary+happy+ending&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7-YWY3ObJAhXEHx4KHfL6BQgQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22happy%20endings%22&f=false) says 2000s for *happy endings* so *OED* is probably right. I also briefly checked Ngram by including the word *massage* but couldn't find anything earlier than 1999.

Answer (score 1):

The following analysis by [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/07/happy-ending.html) does not cite when the expression was first used euphemistically, but it provides interesting facts:

[Happy ending:](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/07/happy-ending.html)

> - Both the noun “end” and the gerund “ending” mean, among other things, a conclusion. So “happy end” and “happy ending” would seem to mean the same thing.
> - Although both are technical correct, “happy ending” is the idiomatic phrase (the one used naturally by a native speaker) when referring to the happy conclusion of a novel, play, movie, and so on.
> - ***The earliest example of the expression in the Oxford English Dictionary is from Memorable Conceits, a 1602 translation of a book by the French writer and printer Gilles Corrozet:***
>
>   - *“A good entrie or beginning is not all, without it haue a happie ending.” (In the original French, “happie ending” is heureuse issue.)*
> - And here’s a citation from a May 10, 1748, letter by Samuel Richardson in which he discusses a scene from his recently published novel Clarissa:
>
>   - *“The greater Vulgar, as well as the less, had rather it had had what they call, an Happy Ending.”*
> - The OED defines “happy ending” as “an ending in a novel, play, etc., in which the plot achieves a happy resolution (esp. by marriage, continued good health, etc.), of a type sometimes regarded as trite or conventional.”

According to the source, the OED does not provide usage examples with the euphemistic meaning, but @ermanem has actually cited one:

> - The dictionary adds that in the US the phrase is also used for “an orgasm, esp. one experienced by a man after sexual stimulation given after (or during) a massage.”
> - The OED doesn’t have an example of this usage, but the comedian Jim Norton uses the phrase in the sexual sense in the title of his 2007 book, *Happy Endings: The Tales of a Meaty-Breasted Zilch*. The [cover](http://d28hgpri8am2if.cloudfront.net/book_images/cvr9781416961055_9781416961055_hr.jpg) shows him lying on a massage table.

Comment: There's another question which is about end versus ending: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/179005/are-the-nouns-end-and-ending-interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Olivia Newton John's song in 1978, "A Little More Love," has the lyrics from John Farrar about a happy ending.

> But it gets me nowhere to tell you "no"
> It gets me nowhere to make you go
> Will a little more love make you
> Star depending
> Will a little more love
> Bring a **happy ending**
> Will a little more love make it right
> Will a little more love make it right.

Comment: Can you explain how your example relates to the question? What is the new information you bring?